# How to save relationship between 2 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot

How to save data from the one form to two tables and save relationship between them?

I have model Company:

```
public function maps()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Map');
}
```

and model Map:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Company');
}
```

and form with inputs:

- company name
- localisation (lat and long from google maps)

and mysql tables:

- companies (id, name, etc.)
- maps (id, lat, long)
- company_map (company_id, map_id)

and store:

```
public function store(CreateCompanyFormRequest $request)
{
$input = Request::all();
$company = new Company($request->all());
Auth::user()->companies()->save($company);
$lat = $request->input('lat');
$long = $request->input('long');
$maps = new Map([
    'lat' => $lat,
    'long' => $long
    ]);
$maps->save();
return $input;
}
```

How to save relationship between Comapny and Map (company_id and map_id)?
Best thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's many-to-many relationship, use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
public function store(CreateCompanyFormRequest $request)
{
    $company = auth()->user()->companies()->create($request->all());
    $maps = Map::create($request-all());
    $company->maps()->attach($map->id);
    return back()->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pivot table `company_map` first of all you should change your relationships:

```
public function maps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Map');
}
```

and

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
}
```

and then you should add:

```
$maps->companies()->attach($company->id);
```

after:

```
$maps->save();
```